# Matplotlib / Seaborn: Make a vertical distplot and a barplot share the Y axis

Tags: matplotlib, plot, seaborn, subplot

I'm trying to create a plot with two subplots (one row, two columns), in which a vertical distplot and a vertical barplot (both from seaborn) share the Y axis. The result should look somewhat like an asymmetric violin plot.

The data for the bar plot is of this form:

```
In[8]: barplot_data[0:5]
Out[8]:
[{'time': 0, 'val': 171.19374169863295},
 {'time': 50, 'val': 2313.8459788903383},
 {'time': 100, 'val': 1518.687964071397},
 {'time': 150, 'val': 1355.8373488876694},
 {'time': 200, 'val': 1558.7682098705088}]
```

I.e., for every time step (in steps of 50), I know the height of the bar. The data for the dist plot is of the form:

```
In[9]: distplot_data[0:5]
Out[9]: [605, 477, 51, 337, 332]
```

I.e., a series of time points of which I'd like the distribution to be drawn.

Here's how I create the bar plot in the right subplot:

```
barplot_df = pd.DataFrame(barplot_data)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharex=False, sharey=True, squeeze=False)
left_ax = axes[0][0]
right_ax = axes[0][1]

sns.barplot(y='time', x='val',
            data=barplot_df,
            orient='h',
            ax = right_ax)
```

The result is pretty much what I want on the right side:

[image: Bar plot on the right side]

Similarly, I can put the dist plot on the left side:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharex=False, sharey=True, squeeze=False)
left_ax = axes[0][0]
right_ax = axes[0][1]

sns.distplot(distplot_data, ax=left_ax, vertical=True)
```

This also works. I think it's kind of strange that the direction of the Y axis is reversed, but whatever:

[image: Distplot left]

However, now I'm just trying to plot them both into the same figure and it wreaks havoc on the dist plot:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharex=False, sharey=True, squeeze=False)
left_ax = axes[0][0]
right_ax = axes[0][1]

sns.barplot(y='time', x='val',
            data=barplot_df,
            orient='h',
            ax = right_ax)

sns.distplot(distplot_data, ax=left_ax, vertical=True)
```

[image: Combined]

I can only imagine that this is because of the axis of the distplot somehow being distorted or something? Does someone know what's going on here?

Comment: A seaborn bar plot is a discrete plot. The first bar is at position 0 on the axis, the second at position 1 etc. So the axis ranges from 0 to number of bars-1. The distplot just uses the numeric data, it ranges from min(data) to max(data). Instead of a seaborn bar plot, better use a matplotlib bar plot, which uses numeric values as well.

Comment: Thanks! It's a bit counter intuitive that seaborn and matplotlib behave differently on their bar plots.

Comment: Well, not really. If seaborn bar plot would be the same as matplotlib bar plot there would not be any reason for seaborn barplot to exist.